# React AWS Amplify Authentication Saves To Federated Identities and User Models

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify

I've set up the Amplify Authentication UI in React, so I can register/sign:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const Profile = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("User: ", user);
        setUser(user);
      })
      .catch((err) => setUser(null));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {user && <h1>Welcome, {user.username}</h1>}
      <AmplifySignOut />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(Profile);
```

[image]

But when I register a new user, the user is saved into Federated Identities User Pools. Shouldn't it be saved into DynamoDB? I've been trying to figure why it isn't saving in there? In addition, I've created a new User type model, thinking that if I register a new account, there will be data populated:

```
type User
  @model(subscriptions: null)
  @key(fields: ["userId"])
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "userId" }, { allow: private, operations: [read] }]) {
  userId: ID!
  posts: [Post] @connection(keyName: "postsByUserId", fields: ["userId"])
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
  following: [Following] @connection(keyName: "followingByUserId", fields: ["userId"])
}
```

Something like this, where userId field will be updated?